# How do RNN's map variable-length sequences to variable-length sequences?

Tags: neural-networks

According to Karpathy's blog "The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Recurrent Neural Networks", recurrent neural networks can map variable-length sequences to variable-length sequences, as shown by the one-to-many, many-to-one, and many-to-many diagrams.

How do RNN's do this mapping of possibly different-length sequences? It seems to me that there would need to be mechanisms that decide whether to accept input or to yield output on any given iteration. I don't see how RNN's have any such mechanisms.